# Prove or disprove : if the $n$th -root of $a_n$ is greater than $1$, then $(a_n)$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

known : almost for every $n$: $a_n>0$,

if  $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1 $,  then $(a_n)$ is convergent (in the broad sense that means it can be $\infty$ )

I thought: to prove $(a_n)$ is not convergent, prove that  $ \sqrt[n]{an}\le 1 $   but didn't succeed.

Also, in direct I didn't succeed a direct proof, and also Ccauchy criterion didn't work for me , I am missing something.

I know that :

there exists $N$ such that for every $n>N ,\: a_n>0 $

and I tried to convey the idea that if $a_n>0$, there exists $M$ such that
$a_n\le M$. Maybe $M$ is a natural number and maybe it's $\infty$, but it is monotonic, so by a theorem, it  must converge (to a real value or $\infty $).

Can some one show me the formal way to approach and solve and explain the paths that we can take in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. Take, for instance$$a_n=\begin{cases}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\2^n&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1$, but $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge in $\Bbb R\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$.